# Are there any side effects of using global 'position:relative'?

Tags: css, position, positioning

I'm seeing that I'm using the combination `position:relative` and `position:absolute` a lot.

In stead of having to declare `position:relative` for each time I use `position:absolute`, I've set it global `* { position:relative; }`.

It seems to work fine, but are there any side effects of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will have to set things back to `position: static` if you ever want to position anything with respect to anything other than its immediate parent.

You will probably want to do this in about 3 months time when it will take hours of work to do it without breaking all sorts of other things (the universe is like that).

Wield CSS like a scalpel, not a sledgehammer.

Comment: Nicely put :) But I can't see when I would do that. I tested a div placed in various places using `fixed` and `absolute` and I had no problem. Also, do you know if it will affect rendering time in anyway?

Comment: "But I can't see when I would do that" — Maybe not today. I wouldn't bet your needs for three months down the line though.

Comment: And performance wise, Opera has some good inf on this: http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/style-profiler-preview

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is that relative positioned elements MIGHT be more heavy to render, leading to a lower framerate for complicated pages. But I'm not even sure about that..
Anyway, I suggest that if you have to build a site that requires to use absolute positioning a lot it's ok to use your method, otherwise do it the standard way

Comment: I just found out that it will affect performance: http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/style-profiler-preview

Comment: I knew it affects the page loading time, the * selector is not a good thing (even though I always use it for box-sizing: border-box). I'm still not sure about the framerate, I couldn't find anything so I guess selectors don't affect it

Comment: Apparently Paul Irish saw it as improving performance on blink at some point https://github.com/csstools/sanitize.css/issues/2#issuecomment-83359006